# Running a migration seed method from a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I've got an application which has a seed method that takes a very long time to run. We want the seed method to remain an option, but we don't want it to be run every time the database has to be updated.

I was asked to find a way to make the seed method run from a controller method so that we could call it at will from an administration panel. Also, it needs to have the ability to have a parameter passed in to specify which database it will be loading, as we want it to be able to load a few different sets of sample data.

I'm fairly new to the MVC framework so I'm unsure if there is a good way to do this, or if someone should even be doing something like this.

Comment: Migration class is simply a regular class you can just new up and run the seed method on that object, cant you?

Comment: In theory that would make sense, I'm having some namespacing issues at the moment but I probably just need to fool around with this some more.

Comment: How long does it take to run?

Comment: Haven't actually timed it, between 15-30 minutes I'd say.